# Vbscript - Object Required for DateLastModified

Tags: date, vbscript, compare

I don't really know what's wrong right here. 
I'm trying to create a vbscript that basically checks two Folders for their files and compare the DateLastModified attribute of each and then copies the source files to the destination folder if the DateLastModified of the source file is newer than the existing one.

I have this code:

```
Dim strSourceFolder, strDestFolder
Dim fso, objFolder, colFiles

strSourceFolder = "c:\users\user\desktop\Source\"
strDestFolder = "c:\users\user\desktop\Dest\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(strSourceFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For each objFile in colFiles
    Dim DateModified
    DateModified = objFile.DateLastModified
    ReplaceIfNewer objFile, DateModified, strSourceFolder, strDestFolder
Next

Sub ReplaceIfNewer (sourceFile, DateModified, SourceFolder, DestFolder)

    Const OVERWRITE_EXISTING = True
    Dim fso, objFolder, colFiles, sourceFileName, destFileName
    Dim DestDateModified, objDestFile

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    sourceFileName = fso.GetFileName(sourceFile)
    destFileName = DestFolder & sourceFileName

    if fso.FileExists(destFileName) Then    
        objDestFile = fso.GetFile(destFileName)    
        DestDateModified = objDestFile.DateLastModified

        msgbox "File last modified: " & DateModified
        msgbox "New file last modified: " & DestDateModified

    End if      


End Sub
```

And I get the error: On line 34, Char 3 "Object required: 'objDestFile'
But objDestFile IS created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use set e.g.:

```
Set objDestFile = fso.GetFile(destFileName)
```

Comment: Omg... thank you! I think I've had too little coffe this morning :)